# How to get one row of each id which matches the specific condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
student_id | subject_name | marks |
-----------------------------------
   1            english        50
   1            maths          70
   2            science        60
   2            english        90
   3            maths          85
   3            english        75
   3            science        98
```

Now, I would like to get one row for each student which consists of the details in which the student got maximum marks.
The details should be student_id, subject_name and marks. And I am using SQL Server.

Comment: your title said `MySQL`. The body said `SQL Server`. So is it `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, RN = row_number() over (partition by student_id order by marks desc)
    FROM   #DDDD
) 
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE  RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RN = row_number() over (partition by student_id order by marks desc)
    FROM   yourtable
) D
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For some versions of SQL Server, the basic method may not work. Try this easy alternative:

```
SELECT student_id, subject_name, marks FROM your_table
WHERE marks = (SELECT MAX(marks) FROM your_table GROUP BY student_id)
```

Alter it in any way you want and in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You can join your table with max mark calculated table :

```
SELECT t1.* FROM  
your_table t1,
( SELECT MAX(marks) maxMark,t.student_id  FROM your_table t GROUP BY t.student_id) as t2
    WHERE t1.student_id=t2.student_id
    and t1.marks=t2.maxMark
```